# R, How to filter dataframe based on bins and get the sum/counts for each column of unknown length?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of species abundance and several environmental variables which I already binned and created a "binned column". I am struggling with getting the sum of abundances for each species per bin. I see many R examples with tidyverse but all seem to use actual names of the column - I have several dataframes, some with hundreds of species names that I do not want to type out.

Example dataframe:

```
head(data)  binned     Acanthamorpha    Belonidae   Blenoids
Site1_1       1           0               2           3
Site2_2       2           2               3           0
Site3_1       1           5               1           0
Site4_3       3           0               0           0
Site3_2       2           0               3           0
```

I labeled by site names with the bin value just for visualization purposes later, but essentially I want to create a smaller dataframe like below:

```
bin    Acanthamorpha    Belonidae   Blenoids
 1          2               3          3
 2          4               6          0
 3          3               0          0
```

I am getting confused with tidyverses filter/mutate/groupby.

I've played around with it a lot but can't really seem to get past just organizing all my rows by the bin value:

```
data %>% filter(binned == 1) %>% gather(binned) %>% ???
```

But the fault here is also calling each value for binned. I'm sure there is a way to break the dataframe up by the bins, then just get the sum for each species as a new row, then save all those rows (5 rows total) as a new dataframe but I cannot get it to work with any of my methods.

Comment: No didn't work. I also wanted to keep the rownames in tact so I tried ```rownames_to_columns('Sites') %>% group_by(binned %>% summarize(across(everything(),sum)) %>% columns_to_rownames('Sites')``` but I get the error ```Error: `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.```

Comment: I also did try it without pushing rownames to a column, in case that was causing an error but I got the same error.

Comment: Just a typo. The issue persisted. I accepted the answer by @Rory S below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
library(tidyverse)

# Reproducing your data
df1 <- tibble(
  binned = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 2),
  Acanthamorpha = c(0, 2, 5, 0, 0),
  Belonidae = c(2, 3, 1, 0, 3),
  Blenoids = c(3, 0, 0, 0, 0)
)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(binned) %>%
  summarise_all(sum)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  binned Acanthamorpha Belonidae Blenoids
   <dbl>         <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1      1             5         3        3
2      2             2         6        0
3      3             0         0        0
```

Comment: Wow yes, can't believe I didn't get summarize_all to work before. I kept using summarize_all('column_name') for specific columns. Thanks so much!